# Can't import store from .ts file to .js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my site.js file i import the store from index.ts

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from '../components/site/App'
import {store} from '../components/site/src/app-config/index.ts'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```js
export const store =  createStore(rootReducer(history), applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

I got problem in the browser console:

> browser.js:34 Uncaught Invariant Violation: You must pass a component
>   to the function returned by connect. Instead received {}